# customize tfs 2017 release management interface

Tags: tfs

I would like to know if it is possible to customize the release management interface for on-premise TFS 2017?  I would like to put some controls like combo boxes, pick lists, etc. on the UI to codify user selections rather than have free form text entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean tasks in release definition, you can custom build/release task through extension, more information, you can refer to [Add a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task) task (apply to TFS2017).

If you mean the general boxes in release definition, no you can’t custom.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I appreciate it.